# WP7 Get listbox item text

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

Is there a way to get the text of a clicked listbox item?

So on click it sets a string to the text in the list box item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a new DataBound App, changed the following method to see 3 ways of getting this:

```
// Handle selection changed on ListBox
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
    if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    var string1 = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).LineOne;
    var string2 = (MainListBox.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).LineOne;
    var string3 = (e.AddedItems[0] as ItemViewModel).LineOne;

    // Navigate to the new page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

    // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
    MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: So what string contains the text?

Comment: `string1`, `sdtring2` and `string3` each contain text.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions but, it knows what line its on and i can use any of the 3 ways?

Comment: Use whichever is best for you. I normally use the third option with a null check first :)

Comment: Do i need to change it for each line or put that one code and it will work for all items in the list box?

Comment: that will work for all items, assuming that you only allow single item selection.

Comment: Yea just what ever one is clicked